# Debugger not attaching to UnityPlayer on Android Device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have a game built on Unity running in an android device.  In theory it should be possible to step through the unity code by attaching to AndroidPlayer at runtime.

Well I followed the rules on how to do this.

1) Created development build with script debugging enabled.

2) run the app with script debugging on wifi that has the player.

Initially it worked. Then perhaps a change or two in my network, and I no longer see AndroidPlayer as an option in MonoIDE to attach to.  Its vanished and for several days now I am not able to debug. Not only that but i really don't know where to check this. I yanked out the ethernet cable so device and Mac are both on same wifi running on single subnet. Nothing seems to help.  But what really dissappoints me is there is really nothing to check in Unity when this type of thing happens. It just try to attach to proess. Hope AndroidPlayer process is there and if  its not. Tough luck.

PS: I should add I am on Unity Pro 4.2.04f.  It worked fine, then who knows what and it stopped finding the AndroidPlayer. What a mess!

PS: Things I have tried.  Pinging to ip address, and telneting to port (successfully to ip:5555)

Note: This is not the Android Debugger I am talking about but a player that needs to be running in the app, and visible to MonoIDE in order to debug.

What I am really trying to understand is what are my options when I cannot see AndroidPlayer as an process to attach to?How does one debug this problem? Are there things in the logg if AndroidPlayer is sucessfully running? How could monodebug not see it?  How do I know it it is or is not running on the devices.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the IP address of the Android device and attempted to ping it? I find that, here in the UK, our BT provided "home hub" will often, randomly, stop routing traffic between devices on the same network.

I find that if I can't debug (and I believe Unity 4.2 still used wifi debugging) then I usually can't print either and it's because the router has stopped routing traffic.

A quick reboot of the router usually fixes it.

PS Just read about the ping being successful. Have you downloaded and run "wireshark" to see what network traffic is happening? At least that will show you what is happening on the network layer.

Other thought, any sort of firewall running on the debugging machine?

Answer (score 0):

Try to:
1) Disable antivirus
2) Disable firewall
3) Deinstall Xamarin (in case when you use VS for debugging)

That did help me when I had the same problem